What information do the bootstrap equations provide for 2D CFT?
I might be missing something obvious, but reading the BPZ paper and the Ginsparg lecture notes, and based on some specific example I tried to work out, I realized I don't understand exactly what the necessity of the bootstrap equations for solving the theory is.
I was looking specifically at the section 5.2 of Ginsparg, where he derives the structure constants for the 2D Ising model. The situation is the following: we need to compute a 4 point correlation function. We have the BPZ partial differential equations, which in the case of the 4 point correlation function of 4 identical fields, reduces to the following ODE that Ginsparg uses:
$$
\left[x(1-x)\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+(1/2-x)\frac{d}{dx}+\frac{1}{16}\right]F(x,\bar{x})=0 \quad (5.7)
$$
Where $F(x,\bar{x})$ is all we need to know to find said correlator, and we also have the cross ratio $x$. Although it is only for identical fields that it is possible to eliminate $z_1,z_2,z_3$ and $z$ and reduce everything to the cross ratio (as far as I can tell), it is possible in any situation to reduce the BPZ PDEs to ODEs for 4-point functions, by using equation (5.19) of BPZ (which I think is applicable, maybe I'm forgetting something here). So for 4-point functions, this is a general situation: we end up with a second order ODE.
Ginsparg solves the ODE. There are 2 independent solutions, but he uses single valuedness of the correlator and normalization to fully determine it. We also know the conformal blocks, which can be determined by conformal symmetry considerations alone. Knowing all that, he expands the correlator so that he reads off the coefficient $C_{\sigma\sigma\epsilon}$. As far as I can tell in this whole process, the bootstrap equations/crossing symmetry were not used at all. So what's the deal with them? Is this just a bad example? Are they necessary in other contexts? And where can I find some explicit calculations about these things?
